# How to set Type of Form Ref in React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I made my Custom Hook for Form, But I made it with Typescript. Here my Hook,

```
const useFormValue = (formRef) => {
// My Code here...
}
```

When I Hover `formRef` in VSCode, It shows

```
Parameter 'formRef' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Usage for my Hook,

```
const { value } = useFormValue(formRef)
```

I want to set Type which shows error when I don't pass `HTMLFormElement Ref` as parameter in `useFormValue`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
import { Ref } from 'react';

const useFormValue = (formRef: Ref<HTMLFormElement>) => {
```

Note that `Ref` means it could either be an object with a `.current` property, or a function. If your code in useFormValue can only work with the object version, you can restrict it more by doing:

```
import { RefObject } from 'react';

const useFormValue = (formRef: RefObject<HTMLFormElement>) => {
```